# What's the meaning of “floor discussion”?

Tags: meaning

What's a **floor discussion** in the following sentence?

> Promptness is necessary so that, by the time the Conference opens,
>   your material will have been compiled for use in a report, a panel
>   discussion, a workshop, a **floor discussion**, or a committee agenda
>   item.

NOTE: I asked this question in [English Language Learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73948/whats-the-meaning-of-floor-discussion) but then thought it is more suited to be posed in here.

Comment: My guess: Discussion in an open session of the conference.

Comment: It's a debate between conference/meeting participants, generally occuring at the end of a presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/floor), one of the floor meanings is:

> c :  the members of an assembly

So in this sense a **floor discussion** is one among the members of a conference.